# How-to select an entry from a list of pairs that meets a condition depending the 2nd element of each pair

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

**Processed data structure**

```
data = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, 100], RandomReal[{10^-8, 10^-1}, 100]}]
```

You can download the actual raw data structure [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hxli31gzrjnrh3w/353_SIM_1M_.xlsx?dl=0).

**Condition description**

Firstly, the decision must be based on the sub-lists 2nd element. Please see example below:

> {{15, **0.0690906**}, {18, **0.095235**}, {17, **0.0282053**}, {9,
>   **0.00283472**}, ...}

Based on the above example, I need to extract a value nearest to `x`, where `x` signifies some specific treshold. Examples can be:

> > {10^-1, 10^-2, 10^-3} etc.

I have tried to build up a solution using a set of configurations involving [Cases](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html), [Select](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [Nearest](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html?q=Nearest). However, I did not succeed.

I have tried using a formulation similar to below:

```
(*Simplified processed data*)    
Select[RandomInteger[{1, 20}, {5, 2}], #[[2]] > 5 &]
```

Based on the generated data, the above would produce desired output. Example:

> {{19, 18}, {9, 11}}

However, my problem involves the condition to be as described above. Based on raw data structure (transposition of column 1 && 3), I have applied following formulation to see what is the actual nearest result:

**Input:**

```
Nearest[dataF[[1]][[All, 2]], 10^-4]
```

In the above `dataF` is processed raw data (transposition of column 1 && 3). Additionally, `dataF` is composed of many similar sets of data as the raw data structure made available to download above; hence `[[1]]` notation used to point towards a specific dataset.

**Output:**

> {0.000101238}

Given the above has output a value which could be used to find a sub-list containing this value, I used following:

**Input:**

```
Select[dataF[[1]], #[[2]] == Nearest[dataF[[1]][[All, 2]], 10^-4] &]
```

**Output:**

> {}

I would appreciate if somebody could point me in the right direction and, perhaps, explain why the above code did not produce any result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[42];
With[{n = 100}, 
  data = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, n], RandomReal[{10^-8, 10^-1}, n]}]]
With[{threshold = 1*^-4, yvals = data[[All, 2]]},
  First @ Extract[data, Position[yvals, First @ Nearest[yvals, threshold]]]]
```

> `{16, 0.000661563}`

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[42]; With[{n = 100}, 
 data = Transpose[{RandomInteger[{1, 20}, n], 
    RandomReal[{10^-8, 10^-1}, n]}]] ;  

  Pick[data, Chop[data[[;; , 2]] - 1*^-4, 0.001], 0]
(*{{16, 0.000661563}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dataF = Catenate@Import["excel.xlsx"];

dataF // Dimensions
```

> {800, 3}

The second column contains the same value:

```
dataF[[All, 2]] // Union
```

> {7.7875*10^-6}

```
sel = First@Nearest[dataF[[All, 3]], 10^-4]
```

> 0.000101238

```
Flatten@Select[dataF, #[[3]] == sel &]
```

> {0.196152, 7.7875*10^-6, 0.000101238}

```
Function[{x}, 
    Flatten@Select[dataF, #[[3]] == 
        First@Nearest[dataF[[All, 3]], x] &]][#] & /@ 
          {10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1}
```

> {{0.196152, 7.7875*10^-6, 0.000101238}, {0.156825, 7.7875*10^-6,
>   0.0009968}, {0.0418247, 7.7875*10^-6, 0.00623}, {0.0418247, 7.7875*10^-6, 0.00623}}

etc.